# wristwatch with millisecond number counter

Tags: javascript

I have exhausted my searching for a watch that shows the milliseconds counting down.

Comment: Do you want a circular watch with a millisecond sweep insanely sweeping around, or do you not mean milliseconds or do you not mean wrist watch?

Answer (score 3):

Strange, it was the [first hit on Google](http://www.seph.dk/projects/javascript-stopwatch-class/).

Comment: People *still* use Google? :P

Comment: @Loktar, from time to time, I happen to visit this site :-)

Comment: Sure doesn't look like a Rolex to me